# Inflating PreferenceScreens at runtime

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-inflate

I have a PreferenceActivity which should display a PreferenceScreen for each of the entries in a list in my app. However, the list is only known at runtime, and so I can't define them in XML. I would like to define a generic screen in XML and then inflate an instance for each entry, but I don't see a way to do this. Anyone have a suggestion?